# Magento: Getting the countries specified for table rates?

Tags: magento

Is there a way to get the countries which were specified when importing the table rates? I know how to do it for "free shipping", its done this way:

```
$freeShippingCountries = explode(',', Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/freeshipping/specificcountry', Mage::app()->getStore()));
```

This is not working for the table rates, I tried, its returning *null* all the time. Is there another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually no, the tablerates data is stored in separate table, you can try something like

```
    $read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');

    $tableRateData = $read->fetchAll("select * from shipping_tablerate");
```

or if you need only countries which are enabled in table rates use

```
    $tableRateData = $read->fetchAll("select distinct dest_country_id from shipping_tablerate");
```